# Android Studio does not detect my Moto G

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I've connected my phone in the Camera mode, I have installed the latest motorola drivers from https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481/action/auth. And I've also installed the avd from
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979

My device is just not showing up in the available devices when I try testing my app. Please help.

Comment: Is this the official site for the drivers  [link](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481/action/auth) as you mentioned? It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Enable USB debugging on the device (Developer options).

Answer (score 2):

I've followed this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qb2olFyoMV4 and it worked well with my Moto G 2nd Generation.

When I try to see the logs from my device on Android Monitor, I had to unlock my device and there was a message asking if it was ok to debug from this computer.
[Allow USB Debug message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81MIt.png)

Hope it works for you too.

Comment: you should summarize the content from the link because sometimes videos are removed from youtube rendering your answer worthless to future readers